# How can I draw a centered string in OpenGL/C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

```
void DrawGLText(string text, float loc_x, float loc_y) {
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
  glRasterPos3f(loc_x, loc_y, 1);
  glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18), text.c_str());
}
```

This is the my code for drawing text at a specific location.  I'd like to adapt it to draw text that's centered on (loc_x, loc_y) rather than left-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`glutBitmapWidth()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node77.html) or [`glutBitmapLength()`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#FontRendering) (from FreeGLUT) to find the width of your string and translate along the X axis by `-textWidth / 2.0f`:

```
// call glRasterPos*() before this
// x/y offsets are in pixels
void bitmapString( void* aFont, const unsigned char* aString, float aXoffset, float aYoffset )
{
    GLboolean valid = GL_FALSE;
    glGetBooleanv( GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION_VALID, &valid );
    if( !valid )
    {
        return;
    }

    GLfloat pos[4] = { 0.0f };
    glGetFloatv( GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos );
    glWindowPos2f( pos[0] + aXoffset, pos[1] + aYoffset );
    glutBitmapString( aFont, aString );
}

// usage
std::string text = "Lorem ipsum";
glRasterPos2f( 50.0f, 100.0f );
const auto* str = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(text.c_str());
const int width = glutBitmapLength( font, str );
bitmapString( font, str, -width / 2.0f, 0.0f );
```

Comment: Hmm... It seems I'm working with a mocked version of GL that doesn't include either of those (and I don't really have the power to change that).  Can  you think of any work-arounds?